# Linux - finding hidden files that are executable by the owner using ls or find command

Tags: linux, bash, find, ls

Well, as the post title says, I need to find the (only) Hidden files that are executable by the Owner using `ls` or `find` command.

I was able to get these..
A command to find all the executable files

`find <dir> -executable -type f`

And, this one's to find all the hidden files

`find . ".*" -ls`

So, I was able to find the hidden files and executables but I couldn't filter only the hidden files that are executable by the Owner.

Comment: `find . -type f -name ".*" -executable -ls`

Comment: See the -perm argument in the manual http://linux.die.net/man/1/find, you'll probably end-up with something like `find ~ -type f -name .\* -perm -o=x -ls`

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca I tried this. Sorry it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `find`,

```
find . -name '.*' -type f -perm /700
```

**Explanation:**

`-perm /700` - find hidden files which is having executable by the owner.

Answer (score 1):

Just combine them:

```
find . -name '.*' -executable -type f
```

Comment: Thanks. Now with this I was able to get the executable hidden files. But, I want only the hidden files executable by the owner.

Answer (score 1):

find  -type f -executeable -name ".*"